# Git Detached Head

Tags: git, git-detached-head

I have run into this Git detached head and haven't found a solution yet that has worked.  Here is my scenario...

I have a `Dev` branch I work on, committed several times and then all of the sudden notice I have a "detached head" and my `Dev` branch is actually 2 commits behind my `Head`. I can navigate back to the head no problem to resolve the issue but then I would lose all commits after the `Head` became detached.

I need to some how merge the 2 commits after my `Dev` branch, with my `Dev` branch to get `Dev` back to the `Head` so I can continue development.

I have tried several things in other Git Detached Head issues on here but none have resolved my particular issue.  Any help is great appreciated.

Comment: I don't this that question link appropriately answers this question at all.

Comment: @shafeen you are correct, this is one of the many posts I read that did not resolve my issue

Comment: @mgrenier: in which case, help us to help you by editing your question to explain *why* the duplicates proposed do not help you.

Comment: @shafeen  - the accepted answer there seems exactly like a solution to this problem.